# How to handle a nested json array to show in a table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, object

[image]

I have this JSON array. I am displaying data in a table. So, How should I put '**transactionData**' inside the main object? i.e. I want the object as

```
{
completeTime: "value",
createTime: "value2",
assigneeName:"value3",
assigneeMap:"value4"
}
```

Since this is a JSON Array, so I need a way to iterate the array and make each of the objects as required.

I can't use the original JSON array since the object **transactionData** is not fixed and its keys might change. So, I don't want to hardcode any value like assigneeMap or assigneeName as it might change.
Hence, I want whatever the values in transactionData object are there, I want to insert it into my main object.

Comment: why can't you use the original json array? please provide more relevant code

Comment: use array.map()

Comment: @depperm I have updated my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 1):

use the `array.map()`, something like this

```
results.map(x=>{
{
completeTime: x.completeTime,
createTime: x.createTime,
assigneeName: x.assigneeName || x.assigneename,
assigneeMap:x.assigneeMap || x.assigneeMap || x.yourChangedKey,
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.prototype.map()

```
const result = arr.map(item => {
    const { completeTime, createTime, data: { transactionData } } = item;
    const { assigneeName, assigneeMap } = transactionData;
    return {
        completeTime,
        createTime,
        assigneeName,
        assigneeMap
    }
});
```